# How to start postponed shared element transition if I am using Fresco?

Tags: android, fresco, shared-element-transition

I am trying to implement shared element transition on 2 `SimpleDraweeView`.

Now everything works well except that the image blinks when I navigate from first activity to the next one.

As we know, in order to avoid such phenomenon, we need to call `postponeEnterTransition()` and call `startPostponedEnterTransition()` when the image is ready.

However I cannot figure out where should I call this if I am using `Fresco`.

Is there a simple callback that I can use for `SimpleDraweeView`'s image ready?

#### Edited on 2018-01-29

Thanks to @Alexander Oprisnik 's answer, I have now gone a bit further. However, after setting everything, I am still able to see the placeholder image during the transition.
Below is my related code:

First, I called `postponeEnterTransition()` in Activity onCreate.

And then after the Image URI has been loaded from the internet, the below method is called:

```
public static void addSharedElementControllerToDrawee (String uri, Activity activity, SimpleDraweeView view) {
    try {
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(uri)).build())
                .setControllerListener(new SharedElementControllerListener(activity))
                .build();
        view.setController(controller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) e.printStackTrace();
        view.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

While the code for `SharedElementControllerListener` is:

```
public class SharedElementControllerListener extends BaseControllerListener {

    private Activity activity;

    public SharedElementControllerListener(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinalImageSet(String id, @Nullable Object imageInfo, @Nullable Animatable animatable) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && activity != null) {
            activity.startPostponedEnterTransition();
        }
        activity = null;
    }
}
```

I set breakpoints on both `postponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()`, and observed that they were both called.
So it looks like `onFinalImageSet()` is not really called after the image is loaded into the `SimpleDraweeView`.

P.S. I have also tried to remove placeholder, but it simply changes to blink between transparency and the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a controller listener and wait for `onFinalImageSet(...)` to be triggered, see http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-to-events.html

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your suggestion, but the blinking still occurs. I have updated my question, much appreciated if you can advise again!

Comment: Just checked, in the Fresco Showcase sample app, the listener is triggered correctly, so not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I may check out the showcase sample app later.